# nouveau error unknown chipset, drm failed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lenovo

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 to my new notebook Lenovo Z50. But when booting up Linux Ubuntu, I get this error:
[image]

And when I try to install Nvidia's driver for GEForce 840M (v. 340.46 or older) the screen freezes. But without Nvidia's GPU drivers I get that nouveau error.

What can I do? Is there possibility that Ubuntu 14.04 gets an update which fixes that error for the devices which faces this error? Or is there any working workaround for this?

Lenovo Z50
Nvidia GeForce 840M
Intel I7-4510U
Graphics Intel® Haswell Mobile (The default one)

Answer (score 1):

Use a command like this

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

This will give you details about your VGA controller, if it is the Intel one (which I think it is) then do

```
sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Then run it this should remove the error.